# Automate SSRS with PowerShell, including filename with parameter

Tags: powershell, reporting-services

I followed this guide (https://sqlbelle.wordpress.com/2015/08/17/automate-ssrs-report-generation-using-powershell/) to automatically generate PDFs from SSRS.

My file only has 1 parameter in comparison to the script they showed.  `"CustomerNo" = '0123456';`
I am trying to get the values assigned to CustomerNo in the filename:
`$fileName = $baseFolder + CustomerNo+"_Sales Report.pdf"`

I've tried quite a few variations of the Customerno+ section of that script but cannot seem to get the right combination. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Try `$fileName = Join-Path -Path $baseFolder -ChildPath ( '{0}_Sales Report.pdf' -f $CustomerNo)`. P.S. In the page you've linked, I see `CustomerID`, not `CustomerNumber`...

Comment: CustomerNo is the parameter in my actual report.

Comment: @Theo My file printed as _Sales Report.pdf

Comment: What about `$fileName = Join-Path -Path $baseFolder -ChildPath ( '{0}_Sales Report.pdf' -f $inputParams['CustomerNo'])` or `$fileName = Join-Path -Path $baseFolder -ChildPath ( '{0}_Sales Report.pdf' -f $inputParams[0])` ?

Comment: $fileName = Join-Path -Path $baseFolder -ChildPath ( '{0}_Sales Report.pdf' -f $inputParams['CustomerNo']) did it.  THANK YOU!!!!!!!!

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: This should be added as an answer and then accepted.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I'm not sure how to do that?